# Github Actions: "error Command "next" not found."

Tags: github-actions

So, one of my github actions workflow is giving me an error:
"Command "next" not found."

i really don't know why next isn't being found, i've done an `ls` earlier and it's running the script in the right folder, next.js is listed as a dependency as seen [here](https://github.com/Neo-Florescence/neo-expensive/blob/main/apps/web/package.json)

i also had a test workflow running, and that worked perfectly

here are the full logs

[image]

this error is very odd, since i just copy and pasted this workflow from another project i have, and there everything works fine

the working deploy workflow: [web_deploy.yml](https://github.com/VitorGouveia/Giffy/blob/master/.github/workflows/web_deploy.yml)

the broken deploy workflow: [web_deploy_broken.yml](https://github.com/Neo-Florescence/neo-expensive/blob/main/.github/workflows/web_deploy.yml)

---

## **Answer**

i was missing a `version` entry in my package.json, yes, that's it

Answer (score 1):

You are missing install dependencies step like [here](https://github.com/Neo-Florescence/neo-expensive/blob/main/.github/workflows/web_deploy.yml#L30-L31)

```
- name: Install dependencies
  run: yarn install
```

It's not github action problem - you are just missing a dependency.
`next` doesn't come with plain `yarn`

Comment: so you're suggesting i remove cache from setup-node?

Comment: i just removed caching from setup-node, yarn install ran as normal, my other services compile as normal, but the web one just breaks, it cant find next.js for some reason, i also removed 'yarn' from the script, i literally have no idea of why this is not working

Comment: OH MY GOD, the problem was that i didnt have a version thing on my package.json, now the workflow is giving a build error

Comment: Well update it or create a new one :) and provide full information about your package.json and full workflow - otherwise it's a guessing game...

Comment: i've solved it already thanks, the problem was that my package.json didn't have the version entry, the other error was some react stuff

thank you